# hotlink protection

Tags: php, hotlinking

i made this simple code to prevent hotlinking my files from my php download file :

```
if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'www.domain.com')!==0)) {
    $redirect='index.php';
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}
```

it's not working , it always redirect me to index.php even if i clicked the link inside my wbesite.
i tried to change the domain to many types like :

> http://www.domain.com 
>  www.domain.com 
>  domain.com 
>  domain

but still the same problem

Comment: what is the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: 1. `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` 2. You need to redirect only if referer exists and isn't equal to your domain. Do nothing otherwise

Comment: why not use .htaccess to do this ? beware that HTTP_REFERER is very unreliable you will end up blocking some legit people

Comment: @Dagon, That would be a valid secondary method.  You should post it as a possible answer.

Comment: i can'tuse htaccess because i'm streaming the download from php file using headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution, i just made a compare between `HTTP_REFERER` and the `HTTP_HOST` using `strpos`, if they match that mean there is no hotlinking. the code :

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
   {
      if(!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
         {
            $redirect='index.php'; 
            header("Location: $redirect");
         }
   }
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this while looking for a `htaccess` code solution and realised it was a more suitable approach. Just wanted to mention that when you paste a link via the empty browser window, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` was `NULL` in my case so the code won't work then. I've left the first condition out altogether myself and it's still behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to use `!== FALSE` instead.  The string could be at position `0`.  Also include zerkms' suggestion:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'www.domain.com') !== FALSE)) {
```

Documentation:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: thanks Brad, it didn't work , i just made a compare between HTTP_REFERER and HTTP_HOST and if they match that mean there is not outdoor request.

Comment: @Alamri, What's in your `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?  What's showing up in your `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: REFERER show me the link of the previous page e.g :`http://domain.com/?p=123` and the HOST only show me the domain e.g `domain.com` so just use strops to match the both strings

Comment: It's been 10 years already since I asked this question, I randomly browsed my questions and saw your answer. How you doing?