# Display a webpage if direct access, but an image if embed content

Tags: php, image

What I want is that with a URL, my site has a URL structure like this, http://mywebsite.com/page/test.gif, the test.gif is a GET parameter, thanks to `.htaccess`, I undestand that I can display a regular website doing so. I also understand that I could display the image directly using a gif file PHP header. What I want is to know if there is a way to check if user is coming from direct access or if the link is embeded and then switch from one option to another.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262436/hotlink-protection

Comment: Are you essentially trying to prevent hotlinking?

Comment: What I want is that: If hotlink, it's a website, if not hotlink, it's a  gif image

Answer (score 0):

```
debug_backtrace() || die ("Direct access not premitted");
```

Add some HTML inside the `die()` command to display a webpage. I will go out on a limb and assume you don't want an entire webpage, just a message that indicates you can't use your images if requested.

Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8965672/1415625)